# Chinese commentary about a Sun Tzu quotation

Tags: transcription

Is this possible for you to transcript (and translate ?) this old chinese text :

http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/23/5wnr.jpg

[url=http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/23/5wnr.jpg][img]https://zupimages.net/up/19/23/5wnr.jpg[/img][/url]

That's commentaries about this Sun tzu "Art of War" quotation :
故用間有五：有鄉間，有內間，有反間，有死間，有生間。

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search for 'art of war':

> http://classics.mit.edu/Tzu/artwar.html
>
> The Art of War
>
> By Sun Tzu
>
> XIII. The Use of Spies
>
> 7. Hence the use of spies, of whom there are five classes: (1) Local spies; (2) inward spies; (3) converted spies; (4) doomed spies; (5) surviving spies.

故用間有五 - Hence there are five classes of spies

有鄉間 -  there are Local spies

有內間 - there are inward spies

有反間 - there are converted spies

有死間 - there are doomed spies

有生間 - there are surviving spies

You can read the explanation on the five kinds of spies on that web-page

Answer (score 0):

I have good and fully understand this part of the text.
That's the other part, the commentaries who is after, what interest and ask me question.

I have a beginning :

鄉間講義開宗集註作因間XX正義作鄉間XXXXX作鄉間XXXXXXXXXX鄉間XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXX間XX

Answer (score 0):

So, what are you thinking about that :

鄉間講義開宗集註作因間直解正義作鄉間直解曰舊本

作鄉間今從之？？下之文以鄉間可為是故今從之識者校正之故者疑證古人之言

曰舉五間之目﻿